# How to call these type of things using Javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
  <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrderGrid,"Grid1")%>
```

I need to call this using javascript?

Can anybody tell me?

```
<%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrderGrid,"Grid1")%>
```

I have a Grid1 and Grid2 in my user control both are under div tag. I need to display one Grid based on user clicks on Row of first Grid1. so My intention was to write

```
 $(doucment).ready(function() { 
     $("#table").click(function() { 
        // Here I need to display Grid2? 
        // I need to call <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrderGrid,"Grid2")%> 
     }); 
 });
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate a little more.

Comment: OK thanks,

 <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrderGrid,"Grid1")%>

I have a Grid1 and Grid2 in my user control both are under div tag,,,

I need to display one Grid based on user clicks on Row of first Grid1.. so My intention was to write

$(doucment).ready(funtion()
{
   $("#table").click(funtion()
{
    // Here I need to display Grid2? I need to call    <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrderGrid,"Grid2")%>
});
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is a server-side call, not a client-side one.  Most likely, the Trirand() method emits a bunch of HTML, and possibly some Javascript, to the browser, thus creating a grid.

If you want to manipulate the grid with Javascript, you need to refer to the grid that is rendered in the browser, not to the server-side call.  But you haven't given me much information about what it is exactly you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,, Exactly I am using this things sir.

http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

I am calling the grid in my view page..so like that on click on row on GRID1 I need to show Grid2?
using Jquery..

Comment: You might want to ask Trirand for assistance, but your final solution will be something that manipulates the final rendered grids.  You won't be calling the Trirand() function from jQuery; that's not how it works.

Comment: Here is a hint: The second grid needs to be initially rendered in a hidden div (visibility: hidden).  You can then use jQuery to show that div.  All you need now is a way to hook up your first grid to a Javascript function.